# How to select for which plot window call function view(90,0)?

Tags: matlab, view, 3d, subplot

I need to apply it for two different plots on user button press not only the last one.
.I have wanted to ask is there some kind of a command that i could select plot from subplot and than proceed with it?
I have GUI and GUI displays me two 3d plots, but when i need to press some buttons for example which changes the view of those plots only one plot is changing the viewing angles other one is doing nothing. 
So is there any tool to make both plots change?

```
 function byheight_pushbutton_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
    % hObject    handle to byheight_pushbutton (see GCBO)
    % eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
    % handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

    %Display contour plot of the currently selected data
    %select the first plot 
    view(90,0), shading interp
    %select the second plot 
    view(90,0), shading interp
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the syntax:

```
view(ax,...)
```

where you can specify which axes you call the `view` function on. For more details, see the [documentation page](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/view.html) for the `view` function.

Arnaud